# plot dataframe: overlay line and bar plot doesn't work for time series index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, bar-chart, overlay

```
import numpy as np                                                                               
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dataframes df0 and df1:
index0 = pd.date_range(start='2014-06-01 00:00:00', end='2014-06-01 00:15:00', freq='1S')          
data0 = np.random.rand(len(index0))                                                                
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data=data0, index=index0, columns=['DF0'])    

index1 = pd.date_range(start='2014-06-01 00:00:00', end='2014-06-01 00:15:00', freq='15S')          
data1 = np.random.rand(len(index1))   
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, index=index1, columns=['DF1'])                                      

# plot df0 and df1:
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(40,10))
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
df0.plot.line( color="r", ax = ax1)
df1.plot.bar( color ='b', linewidth = 5, ax = ax2, alpha = 0.7)
plt.show()
```

I can overlay the dataframes as two line plots or as two barplots. But however hard I try, I can't manage to overlay a line plot with a bar plot or the other way round? With the code above I only get the barplot of df1 but don't see the lineplot of `df0`. What do I have to do differently?

Answer (score 1):

`bar` plot takes categorical (string) values only as the x values. hence simple hack can be converting the time stamps to strings.

when you feed the float values, it converts them into str thereby they are not matching with the index of line plot x-values.

`df0.index = df0.index.map(str)`

Secondary axis would also be not required for this.

Try this!

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create dataframes df0 and df1:
index0 = pd.date_range(start='2014-06-01 00:00:00',
                       end='2014-06-01 00:15:00', freq='1S')
data0 = np.random.rand(len(index0))
df0 = pd.DataFrame(data=data0, index=index0, columns=['DF0'])
df0.index = df0.index.map(str)

index1 = pd.date_range(start='2014-06-01 00:00:00',
                       end='2014-06-01 00:15:00', freq='15S')
data1 = np.random.rand(len(index1))
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, index=index1, columns=['DF1'])

# plot df0 and df1:
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(40, 10))
ax = df0.plot.line(color="r")
df1.plot.bar(color='b', linewidth=5, ax=ax, alpha=0.7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the very helpful tip! I will try it out later and give a feedback! But one question: the DF0-data seem to have been changed from a 1-sec to a 15-sec frequency in the combined bar and line plot? How could I have a lineplot-curve with the original 1-sec frequency?

Comment: I have the impression, that the different frequencies ( 1sec and 15 sec) are causing problems, as can be seen, if we change the order of the line and bar plot: first plot df1:   df1.plot.bar(color='b', linewidth=5, ax=ax, alpha=0.7)    than plot df0:    df0.plot.line(color="r", ax = ax)  /  plt.show()             
df1 seems to be compressed by 1/15th